# Android fragments, illegalargumentexception

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, fragment

I have actionbarcompact library for creating tablayout.
but when i click on the tabs very fast then Illegalargumentexcpetion is thrown

when I went through the logs, then I have observed oncreate of fragment is called before ondestroy of other fragment.
as container id is different for each tab. Illegalargument exception: no view found for id is thrown.

Any suggestions to solve this issue.

```
stack trace
02-19 14:20:11.601: D/FragmentManager(21544):     #16: MoreFragment{4203be70 #16 id=0x7f060176       tag_more_fragment}
02-19 14:20:11.601: D/FragmentManager(21544):       mFragmentId=#7f060176 mContainerId=#7f060176  mTag=tag_more_fragment
02-19 14:20:11.602: D/FragmentManager(21544):       mState=0 mIndex=16 mWho=android:fragment:16 abackStackNesting=0
02-19 14:20:11.602: D/FragmentManager(21544):       mAdded=true mRemoving=false mResumed=false mFromLayout=false mInLayout=false
02-19 14:20:11.602: D/FragmentManager(21544):       mHidden=false mDetached=false mMenuVisible=true mHasMenu=false
02-19 14:20:11.602: D/FragmentManager(21544):       mRetainInstance=true mRetaining=false mUserVisibleHint=true 
02-19 14:20:11.603: D/FragmentManager(21544):       mFragmentManager=FragmentManager{41fb92f8 in MenuActivity{421ccb08}}
02-19 14:20:11.603: D/FragmentManager(21544):       mActivity=com.scgp.ab.MenuActivity@421ccb08
02-19 14:20:11.603: D/FragmentManager(21544):   Added Fragments:
02-19 14:20:11.603: D/FragmentManager(21544):     #0: CustomProgressDialogFragment{42587140 #15 tag_custom_progress_dialog}
02-19 14:20:11.603: D/FragmentManager(21544):     #1: DealerFragmentStack{42524e60 #2 id=0x1020011 DealerFragmentStack}
02-19 14:20:11.604: D/FragmentManager(21544):     #2: MoreFragment{4203be70 #16 id=0x7f060176 tag_more_fragment}
02-19 14:20:11.604: D/FragmentManager(21544):   Fragments Created Menus:
02-19 14:20:11.606: D/FragmentManager(21544):     #0: SellingDealerDetailsFragment{41f291e8 #14 id=0x7f0600d1 tag_selling_dealer_details_fragment}
02-19 14:20:11.607: D/FragmentManager(21544):   FragmentManager misc state:
02-19 14:20:11.607: D/FragmentManager(21544):     mActivity=com.scgp.ab.MenuActivity@421ccb08
02-19 14:20:11.607: D/FragmentManager(21544):     m       Container=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$2@4218a780
02-19 14:20:11.607: D/FragmentManager(21544):     mCurState=5 mStateSaved=false mDestroyed=false
02-19 14:20:11.608: D/FragmentManager(21544):   View Hierarchy:
02-19 14:20:11.608: D/FragmentManager(21544):     com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42562fc0 V.E..... ... 0,0-720,1184}
02-19 14:20:11.608: D/FragmentManager(21544):       com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout{4247d508 V.E..... ... 0,0-720,1184 #1020312 android:id/action_bar_overlay_layout}
02-19 14:20:11.609: D/FragmentManager(21544):         android.widget.FrameLayout{425a3228 V.E..... ... 0,242-720,1184 #1020002 android:id/content}
02-19 14:20:11.609: D/FragmentManager(21544):           android.widget.FrameLayout{42554ed0 V.E..... ... 0,0-720,942 #1020011 android:id/tabcontent}
02-19 14:20:11.609: D/FragmentManager(21544):             android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout{4228ba28 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
02-19 14:20:11.609: D/FragmentManager(21544):               android.widget.LinearLayout{420a1420 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
02-19 14:20:11.610: D/FragmentManager(21544):                 android.widget.FrameLayout{4219faa8 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f0600d1 app:id/dealer_fragment}
02-19 14:20:11.611: D/FragmentManager(21544):         com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer{422b7ab8 V.ED.... ... 0,50-720,242 #1020313 android:id/action_bar_container}
02-19 14:20:11.611: D/FragmentManager(21544):           com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView{422a1460 V.E..... ... 0,0-720,96 #1020314 android:id/action_bar}
02-19 14:20:11.612: D/FragmentManager(21544):             android.widget.LinearLayout{4255c168 VFE...C. ... 17,0-427,96}
02-19 14:20:11.612: D/FragmentManager(21544):               com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView$HomeView{42575840 V.E..... ... 0,0-80,96}
02-19 14:20:11.612: D/FragmentManager(21544):                 android.widget.ImageView{42523de8 G.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #102025c android:id/up}
02-19 14:20:11.613: D/FragmentManager(21544):                 android.widget.ImageView{425a20f0 V.ED.... ... 8,16-72,80 #102002c android:id/home}
02-19 14:20:11.613: D/FragmentManager(21544):               android.widget.LinearLayout{4256f900 V.E..... ... 80,24-410,72}
02-19 14:20:11.614: D/FragmentManager(21544):                 android.widget.TextView{42504950 V.ED.... ... 0,0-314,48 #1020266 android:id/action_bar_title}
02-19 14:20:11.614: D/FragmentManager(21544):                 android.widget.TextView{42502520 G.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020267 android:id/action_bar_subtitle}
02-19 14:20:11.614: D/FragmentManager(21544):             com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView{420f7318 V.ED.... ... 608,0-720,96}
02-19 14:20:11.615: D/FragmentManager(21544):               com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuPresenter$OverflowMenuButton{42596b70 VFED..C. ... 0,0-112,96}
02-19 14:20:11.615: D/FragmentManager(21544):           com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView{4244f028 G.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020315 android:id/action_context_bar}
02-19 14:20:11.616: D/FragmentManager(21544):           com.android.internal.widget.ScrollingTabContainerView{424bf0d8 VFED.... ... 0,96-720,192}
02-19 14:20:11.616: D/FragmentManager(21544):             android.widget.LinearLayout{4255ea28 V.ED.... ... 0,0-968,96}
02-19 14:20:11.616: D/FragmentManager(21544):               com.android.internal.widget.ScrollingTabContainerView$TabView{425928b0 VFE...C. ... 0,0-242,96}
02-19 14:20:11.617: D/FragmentManager(21544):                 android.widget.ImageView{42476988 V.ED.... ... 58,20-114,76}
02-19 14:20:11.617: D/FragmentManager(21544):                 android.widget.TextView{42559860 V.ED.... ... 114,31-183,64}
02-19 14:20:11.617: D/FragmentManager(21544):               com.android.internal.widget.ScrollingTabContainerView$TabView{425a4c00 VFE...C. ... 244,0-486,96}
02-19 14:20:11.618: D/FragmentManager(21544):                 android.widget.ImageView{424b2b78 V.ED.... ... 32,20-88,76}
02-19 14:20:11.618: D/FragmentManager(21544):                 android.widget.TextView{42561780 V.ED.... ... 88,31-210,64}
02-19 14:20:11.618: D/FragmentManager(21544):               com.android.internal.widget.ScrollingTabContainerView$TabView{425b9348 VFE...C. .S. 488,0-730,96}
02-19 14:20:11.618: D/FragmentManager(21544):                 android.widget.ImageView{424caa00 V.ED.... .S. 49,20-105,76}
02-19 14:20:11.619: D/FragmentManager(21544):                 android.widget.TextView{42568058 V.ED.... .S. 105,31-193,64}
02-19 14:20:11.619: D/FragmentManager(21544):               com.android.internal.widget.ScrollingTabContainerView$TabView{425c22d8 VFE...C. ... 732,0-974,96}
02-19 14:20:11.619: D/FragmentManager(21544):                 android.widget.ImageView{4256c9b8 V.ED.... ... 59,20-115,76}
02-19 14:20:11.620: D/FragmentManager(21544):                 android.widget.TextView{424d8100 V.ED.... ... 115,31-183,64}
02-19 14:20:11.620: D/FragmentManager(21544):         com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer{424b8478 G.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020316 android:id/split_action_bar}


02-19 14:20:11.623: D/AndroidRuntime(21544): Shutting down VM
02-19 14:20:11.623: W/dalvikvm(21544): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41674d28)
02-19 14:20:11.626: E/AndroidRuntime(21544): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-19 14:20:11.626: E/AndroidRuntime(21544): Process: com.scgp.ab, PID: 21544
02-19 14:20:11.626: E/AndroidRuntime(21544): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f060176 (com.scgp.ab:id/more_fragment) for fragment MoreFragment{4203be70 #16 id=0x7f060176 tag_more_fragment}
02-19 14:20:11.626: E/AndroidRuntime(21544):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:919)
02-19 14:20:11.626: E/AndroidRuntime(21544):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
02-19 14:20:11.626: E/AndroidRuntime(21544):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
02-19 14:20:11.626: E/AndroidRuntime(21544):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
02-19 14:20:11.626: E/AndroidRuntime(21544):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
02-19 14:20:11.626: E/AndroidRuntime(21544):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-19 14:20:11.626: E/AndroidRuntime(21544):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-19 14:20:11.626: E/AndroidRuntime(21544):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-19 14:20:11.626: E/AndroidRuntime(21544):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5083)
02-19 14:20:11.626: E/AndroidRuntime(21544):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-19 14:20:11.626: E/AndroidRuntime(21544):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-19 14:20:11.626: E/AndroidRuntime(21544):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
02-19 14:20:11.626: E/AndroidRuntime(21544):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
02-19 14:20:11.626: E/AndroidRuntime(21544):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace...

Comment: stack trace is too big, only posted part of it

Answer (score 0):

You said, **as container id is different for each tab** why so. It should be one frame layout, the container, and on tab selections you should replace you fragments withing the same container.

Also, the error says,

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f060176
```

which means that the view is missing for your MoreFragment. Initialize it and ensure the above, it should work.

For an example, see [here.](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/implementing-fragment-tabs-in-android/)

Comment: app has requirement that when back button is clicked, in that tab we have to display history related to that tab itself, when it reaches root fragment in that tab then app has to logout. And this exception is occuring only when I use two fingers to change the tabs fastly.